# Google App Engine Nodejs flex, does it utilise all cores of the instances, or do I have to manually create processes?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to fork new processed so that my NodeJs server can utilise load efficiently.

I am running my NodeJs app on Google App Engine flexible environment, does app engine itself utilize all cores of the instances OR not, because if it doesn't then I would manually have to do it from my end which I didn't find anywhere?